# Mysql select with inet_aton fails

Tags: mysql, ip

in a Mysql database I have a table in which I am trying to store IPv4 addresses. The table is composed by 2 columns: "_id" (primary key) and an integer column where I'd like to store the ip addresses using INET_ATON. I insert a record into a table with the following command and it works with no problem:

```
INSERT INTO db_name.table (IPv4) VALUES (INET_ATON('151.20.141.163'))
```

However when I try to get the id of the ip that I stored, the query return no record.

```
SELECT _id FROM db_name.table WHERE IPv4 = INET_ATON('151.20.141.163')
```

Where I am getting wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `INET_ATON()` takes a number, not a string - it is not what you are looking for!

Comment: @EugenRieck: no, it takes a string, see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior given IPv4 as `INT UNSIGNED` just as Stanislav said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe problem in type of your IPv4 field. It must be INT UNSIGNED, not INT ([Mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton))